# Use a COM component written with .NET 4.7 inside an application using .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

we have an application (Microsoft Dynamics 2008) using .NET 3.5.
We've created a bunch of .NET 4.7 components.
Because we can't mix .NET versions we intend to use the new (.NET 4.7 components) as COM components.
Can we use a COM component created with (C#) .NET 4.7 inside an application developped (or using) .NET 3.5 ?

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple COM component based on 4.7 and calling it from your Dynamics application?

Comment: Actually I created the 4.7 compoentn and the customer using Dynamics tried. They use VS 2008 (!) but they just don't see the COM component among others though it seems to be registered (seen in regedit). I suspected VS would prevent the COM component to be displayed because od compatibility issues. I can't explain why the  component doesn' show otherwise.

Comment: Finally we found no way to do it and had to port all .NET 4.7 to 3.5.